# Multiple charsets — æ ø å

Tags: html, character-encoding

I'm from Denmark where we have æ ø and å. I am currently using this charset:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' />
```

However, as you can see on http://www.bonusrunner.net/betfair.php, while there is no problem in the text in the main area, my headers, menu text, etc. do not show correctly.

As soon as I change the charset to

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
```

it switches, and suddently my headers, menu text and so on display correctly.

Can I use multiple charsets, or is there another solution?

Comment: Are you using a server-side language like PHP? If yes, which one?

Comment: use this code &oslash; where you would normally put it. N&oslash; need to over think. (in case it doesnt show correctly: & oslash; minus the space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use multiple character sets.

What you need to do is *convert* the HTML, PHP and JavaScript files to UTF-8 — they are probably all currently encoded as `ISO-8859-1` (Latin1).

Comment: And how do I convert the html file?

Comment: @CasperSlynge - It depends on the OS and application. On Windows, the free notepad++ allows you to save files with whatever encoding.

Comment: open it in a decent text-editor/ide, such as notepad++ / eclipse / etc, and use its convert to utf-8 function. you may also want to change your database connection charset to utf-8 and set your collation to whatever you use in denmark.

Comment: You don't *have to* use [`UTF-8`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) since HTML can use [`character references` aka `entities`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) to include *any* character in an HTML page using *any* encoding. Your problem was probably that something in your PHP used one encoding such as `UTF-8` while your HTML used `ISO-8859-1`. These days it's much better to avoid any such mismatches from the start by doing everything in `UTF-8` all the time.